# Problem with Hindi keyboard on Android 2.3 emulator

Tags: android, keyboard, android-sdk-2.3, hindi

I have selected some of the languages (like Hindi, English(India), English(United Kingdom) etc.) from **`Input languages`** option in **`Android keyboard settings`** in my emulator (Android 2.3 API). But the problem is that neither it is showing HINDI characters on Soft Keyboard nor displaying some of the Numbers on the keys `e y u i o`.

Problem is exactly shown in below given screenshot:

[image]

Also it is displaying rectangular boxes instead of characters.

Comment: And your question? I take it you want to get a Hindi keyboard on an Android device, but please, why don't _you_ say that, _not me_ - it's your question!

Comment: Hi vikas I have same problem here ,u got any Solution ? if yes pls give suggetion .

Comment: @Parag: Please follow the link given in the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this [Android Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618). If you read towards the end (December 2010), you will see discussions of Gingerbread (Android v2.3) and that although it has gone some way to supporting Hindi language, it is still not providing full support 'out of the box'.

Answer (score 2):

i tried changing fonts in platforms/android9/data/fonts folder and then created new avd.

please try krutidev010 font is it working then.