# Use hindi in android

Tags: android, localization

I want to create an android application in which the user should be able to select a language of his choice(English/ Hindi/ Marathi).

I have checked some android forums and found that android does not support Devanagari fonts.

Is there a solution?  Also, is there a solution without rooting the device?

Comment: Checkout my post here for solution:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779162/unable-to-see-indian-language-characters-even-in-android-2-3/30234016#30234016

Answer (score 2):

As Devanagari fonts are not supported by Android, you can still give that support to your Application.

For Hindi font copy font file (saral.ttf or Shusha.ttf or any font hindi file) to your asset folder. then use the following code.

```
 TextView text_view = new TextView(this);

 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "saral.TTF");

 text_view.setTypeface(font);

 text_view.setText("हिंदी");
```

the same way u can give support for marathi....

Answer (score 0):

you can use following i18n solution for different languages

http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/01/17/translating-android-applications-i18n/

http://www.kobu.com/i18n/android/index-en.htm