# Android emulator does not display Hindi font

Tags: android, localization, android-emulator

I changed the locale to hi_IN on the emulator. When I start my application (or even the home screen) on the emulator, all I see is boxes reminiscent of "i dont know how to render this font". Any input on why this might be happening and how to get rid of this is most welcome. I need to display the hindi font in order to test localization of my application.

Thanks,
Sriram.

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478105/problem-with-hindi-keyboard-on-android-2-3-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not yet fully support Hindi (droid fonts):
[Feature request: support Hindi characters in the droid fonts](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618)