# How to show Hindi(non-english) webpages using web view in android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-webview, android-websettings

I am developing an android application where I need to load a URL which contains the Hindi fonts in web view.

I used the following code for this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

This code is working fine in most of the latest devices and showing Hindi contents properly.
**But in Android 2.2, 2.3 or other lower versions, it is showing boxes rather than Hindi charactors.**

**How can I support web view to be enabled for non-english test so my application can run on all devices.**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have u refer it http://stackoverflow.com/a/8203564/1915697

Comment: @Yogesh, Thanks for your reply. I have already refer this. But I am not clear, how to replace system/fonts with downloaded hindi fonts? And this approach will work on all devices? Please reply me in detail.

Comment: You should overwrite /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf using adb or another tool. Make sure to have a backup of the file first.

Comment: please refer link if you are not able to push file using adb http://www.pocketmagic.net/2009/05/write-on-the-android-read-only-file-system/#.UgSNc3YYZ3C

Comment: For this, we have to root the device? If yes, then I do not want to root the device.

Comment: Which type of url you are loading means from local or from web like http ??

Comment: I am loading web url like http... This website contains English and Hindi fonts both. My web view showing Engilsh fonts properly but Hindi fonts are not showing here. Small boxes are there in place of Hindi fonts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5417710/1915697 your solution

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. Let me try, if it can work for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35122/discussion-between-manoj-agarwal-and-yogesh-tatwal)

Answer (score 1):

try the below link :[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5417710/1915697)

```
private boolean copyFile(Context context,String fileName) {
        boolean status = false;
        try { 
            FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // Close the streams
            out.close();
            in.close();
            status = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in copyFile:: "+e.getMessage());
            status = false;
        }
        System.out.println("copyFile Status:: "+status);
        return status;
    }
```

3.You have to call above function only once (you have to find some logic for this).

```
copyFile(getContext(), "myfont.ttf");
```

4.Use the below code to set value for your webview. Here I am using CSS to set font.

```
private String getHtmlData(Context context, String data){
    String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/verdana.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';}</style></head>";
    String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body>"+data+"</body></html>" ;
    return htmlData;
 }
```

5.You can call the above function as below

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(activity,htmlData) , "text/html",  "utf-8", "about:blank");

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Me also struggled with this for one day but finally found a solution.

Just add these two lines of code it will work

```
 WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```