# In android phonegap application language (Indian language Hindi) font is worked in android emulator but it is not working in real device.

Tags: android

I created an android phonegap application which displays information in multiple languages like Hindi, Fijian, etc. Hindi language content displays properly in properly in emulator but it is not working on actual android device. It displays a small square box.

I'll explain the steps:

- I used web font converter and converted `de.ttf`, it generated 3 files.
- I copied all theses files to folder named "font" in my project directory.
- I added `font-face` in css.

I called the `font-face` in a div and added Hindi text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of android on emulator and on phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing [Android emulator does not display Hindi font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478105/problem-with-hindi-keyboard-on-android-2-3-emulator) answer shows the issue.

[Problem with Hindi keyboard on Android 2.3 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478105/problem-with-hindi-keyboard-on-android-2-3-emulator) is another duplicate.

From what I understand the Hindi is not implemented fully in older phones. It likely works in your emulator due to your emulator's operating system version being higher than the phone. I suggest you change create a new emulator image with the same version as phone and test it. If it does not work on emulator then bump the OS version up until it does. This will have to be your apps minimum OS version.

If for some reason at the same version the text does display correctly, then something else is going on.

Comment: Yes I know. It seems it doesn't have full character set: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618 - google has added further support but hasn't solved it. Please find the version of phone and version of emulator you are running and reply to my comment above.

Comment: Version of phone :2.2.1.
Version of emulator: 4.0.

Comment: Downgrade emulator to 2.2 and it shouldn't work on that either. Follow my instructions above. It is due to phone version.

I suggest you use sprites for each letter; however there may be a better way.

Comment: Thanks alot. Plz provide the steps to downgrade emulator to 2.2.

Comment: Go to adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ run android 
Tools->Manage AVDS->Edit

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html Will answer more of your questions. Cheers.